# SpeechRecognition sr.microphone command triggers windows installer

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Python's speechrecognition library and have successfully installed the required components. However, when executing my code (see picture) the sr.Microphone command triggers an install window. This happens for whichever microphone I set as default (look snippets). Does anyone have any suggestions?

[mic channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neKHh.png) [code + windows prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsOKd.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've been able to use "listen()" correctly. I'm not really sure how I solved it but I did the following since last time:

1. Downgrade from Python 3.7 to python 3.6
2. Install ffmpeg

(I'm on Windows 10 btw)